# How to load more data for a given model after it is already returned by EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm implementing a new feature for our server and as I've faced this 'issue' before I thought that EF Core may have something to help me with that.

Basically, I have three models:

```
public class User {
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required] public CloudSaveProfile SaveProfile { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class CloudSaveProfile {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CloudSaveData> Data { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class CloudSaveData {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [Required] public CloudSaveProfile Profile { get; set; }
    [Required] public string KeyName { get; set; }
    [Required] public byte[] Data { get; set; }
}
```

A Service class

```
public class CloudSaveService {
    public CloudSaveProfile GetProfile(User user) {
        if (user.SaveProfile != null) {
            return user.SaveProfile;
        }

        //Query EF for the save profile

        return user.SaveProfile;
    }
}
```

And lastly, a Controller that has API endpoints to call this service.
In the `User` model class there's a reference to `CloudSaveProfile`, when the controller calls the service it must pass the user and the data to be saved. In my vision, the controller doesn't have to know anything about how this service stores and retrieves the data, so the controller doesn't need to include `CloudSaveProfile` when loading the user, all the controller knows is that the service is asking for the user, and that's all. When this user reaches the service, the controller might have not included the profile and the service would need to load it by sending another query to EF.

So, the question here is, is there a way to include the `SaveProfile` entity to the user without having to re-query for the whole user like so

```cs
var newUser = _context.Users.Include(x => x.SaveProfile).SingleOrDefault(x => x == user);
//OR 
var newUser = _context.Users.Include(x => x.SaveProfile).SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == user.Id);
```

And just a note: I'm NOT looking for a way to do Lazy loading on this property

Comment: It depends. If the `User` class contains the `CloudSaveProfile.Id` value needed to load the `CloudSaveProfile`, then yes, you can use explicit loading. Otherwise there is no other way than requerying the `User` plus related data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explicitly load the related entity like this:

```
context.Entry(user).Reference(u => u.SaveProfile).Load();
//OR
context.Entry(user).Reference("SaveProfile").Load();
```

It will then be available on the existing user as:

```
var profile = user.SaveProfile;
```

HTH